# can't access my supermicro IPMI remote console

Tags: port, video, ipmi

This is my first post, this site it's great, and i hope you can help me with my problem.

I have a supermicro MB X8STI-F and I can access the remote interface browse the server status and everything, BUT when i try to access the remote console i get the message: "Error opening video socket"

I tried to connect from a Windows XP sp3 machine from both Firefox and IE 8 and also from a Windows Vista SP1 both x86, and of course with the latest java update.

Also my datacenter has by default all ports closed, so i requested to open these ports: 80 443 22 5900 TCP i don't know if i'm missing something, i hope you can help me since i really require this feature.

Thanks for your assistance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a similar motherboard - X8DTH-6F. Doing a quick tcpdump of connecting to the IPMI controller and loading up the remote console shows traffic on port 5901. Opening that port as well may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with opening UDP port 623.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a few problems with their IPMI. Try updating the firmware. If you search for the motherboard model and go to the homepage for that board there's a link on the top right next to the picture of the board. It says something about IPMI Firmware. Download that, unzip the .bin file and upload it to the BMC through the browser interface.